# Show lines one by one in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to unhide some < P > elements when a button is clicked, however I want to unhide them one at a time, in the order they appear on the page, each time the button is clicked rather than all at the same time, anyone have any ideas?

CSS:

```
p 
{ 
    display: none; 
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#show").click(function()
    {
        $("p").show();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<P>Line 1</P>
<P>Line 2</P>
<P>Line 3</P>
<button type="button" id="show">Next</button>
```

All three together:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test 1</TITLE>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>p { display: none; }</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#show").click(function(){
$("p").show();
});
});
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>Line 1</P>
<P>Line 2</P>
<P>Line 3</P>
<button type="button" id="show">Next</button> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`:hidden` jQuery pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) in conjunction with [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first) (which gives you only the first element in the set in document order), so in your `click` handler:

```
$("p:hidden").first().show();
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/xoxoyati/1)

Comment: Cheers both, I've gone with this one, nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0;
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p:eq("+i+")").show();
    i++;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add some container for your paragraphs, and check display property of paragraphs`

```
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Test 1</TITLE>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>p { display: none; }</style>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#show").click(function(){    
      findParagraph();
      });
    });

    var pars = $('.container').find('p');
    function findParagraph(){    
      $.each(pars,function(index,val){
       if( $(val).css('display') == 'none'){
          $(val).show();
          return false;
       }    
      });
    });
    </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <div class="container">
    <P>Line 1</P>
    <P>Line 2</P>
    <P>Line 3</P>

    </div>
    <button type="button" id="show">Next</button> 
    </BODY>
    </HTML>`
```

Comment: Good of you to make the effort for the OP, but your `findParagraph` is just a reimplementation of the `:hidden` pseudo-selector (and isn't nearly as thorough). No need for reinventing the wheel here...

Comment: Maybe another look for the question can help to understand such a thing in the future. The :hidden pseudo-selector is a superb way to solve the problem.